# Easy way to switch VGA/DVI cable for a LCD monitor

Tags: display, dvi, vga

I got a Mac Mini(DVI) and a laptop(VGA) sharing same LCD monitor. When using Mac, I need to unplug VGA on the monitor and plug DVI back, vise versa. It's inconvenient to plug/unplug the cable on the back of monitor. Is there any way to make this process easier like some kind of switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of monitor do you have?

One of the main reasons I bought my Dell display is that it has both DVI *and* VGA inputs. I just plug each computer into one of the inputs, and the button on the front of the display switches between the two (it's also got S-Video, composite, and component, although I've never needed those).

Any chance yours has any additional inputs besides DVI?

Comment: Thanks for all answers. Dori's solution is exactly what I want. I didn't realize that the monitor can switch b/t 2 sources.

Answer (score 3):

A [KVM switch](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817107407) perhaps? You can use a VGA to DVI adapter with this switch and it will work fine.  I have 2 of these (the 4 port versions actually) and they work great.

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817394013) is an even better KVM solution for your purpose since you are using laptops.  This KVM switch has a push button for machine selection so you wouldn't need to plug any keyboard into it at all.

Comment: I was about to say overkill but that is a pretty small KVM switch. And for only $17...

Comment: The [product page](http://www.iogear.com/product/GCS62/) gives the impression it doesn't work with Macs -- particularly as it requires PS/2 mice and keyboards.

Comment: with a ps2 to usb adapter it should work fine, but you would need an extra keyboard. i use mine with an adapter like that because i have a usb keyboard and mouse, and it works great. as for the mac part i cannot comment, but i know it works with windows and Linux.